# Consuming a Silverlight-Enabled WCF Service in WPF

Tags: wpf, silverlight, wcf

I have an existing Silverlight-Enabled WCF Service. Now I am writing a WPF. Can I consume that same service or do I need to write a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn't change the binding used in the template, then it will work find in WPF as well. The only binding which is supported in SL and not in WPF is the `PollingDuplexHttpBinding` (or the `PollingDuplexBindingElement` in a custom binding).

Comment: if there is no other caveat, let's say I proceed. At some later data I decide I need a duplex service because some service process takes a while, and I want that service to notify the client. Do I simply declare to bindings, one for WPF and one for Silverlight?

Comment: Yes, in this case you'll need two endpoints, one for SL and another for WPF. The SL one will use the `PollingDuplex` binding, while the one for WPF will use one of the duplex-enabled bindings available in the full framework (`WSDualHttpBinding`, `NetTcpBinding`, etc).